# client_name=undefined client_version=undefined in horizon logs

Tags: horizon

I have set up a local Horizon instance, version `horizon-v0.16.0`. I can start horizon, but when I hit the url `http://ip:8000` I am getting the following messages in the logs:

> time="2019-02-25T12:25:11.577Z" level=info msg="Starting request" **client_name=undefined client_version=undefined** forwarded_ip= host="ec2-xx-x-xxx-xxx.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8000" ip=xx.xxx.xxx.xx ip_port="xx.xxx.xxx.xx:25379" method=GET path="/" pid=27475 req="ip-xxx-xx-xx-xxx/h5J608CV1X-000001" streaming=false

Where can I set the values for these two undefined fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are non standard http headers `X-Client-Name` and `X-Client-Version`. You may set them in your client app if you somehow need to debug/keep track of them. Or just ignore it.

Source:
https://github.com/stellar/go/blob/dac48f24ba77a46bb9a0f6e2842ca2072df8c02c/services/horizon/internal/middleware.go#L52

Quick demo:

```
curl -H "X-Client-Name: myname" -H "X-Client-Version: 1.0" localhost:8000
```